# Swift Localization issue

Tags: swift, swift3

I have this extension:

```
func localized() -> String {
    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
}
```

It works fine, but if the user changes the language on the phone to one we don't support, the UI will show "example_label". I would like for it default to the english translation if it does not find one for the current iOS language settings.

How can I do this?

**Fix:**
Not sure if I will use this, not the best code/approach, but this works.

```
func localized() -> String {
    var localizedString = NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    if self == localizedString {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("en", ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = NSBundle(path: path!)

        localizedString = NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
    return localizedString
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for this exact function (`NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:bundle:value:comment:)`)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1418095-nslocalizedstring) is really lacking, but there's [a similar function, `localizedString(forKey:value:table:)`, with complete documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1417694-localizedstring) It likely acts in a similar way.

> **value**
>
> The value to return if key is nil or if a localized string for key can’t be found in the table.
>
> ...
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A localized version of the string designated by key in table tableName. This method returns the following when key is nil or not found in table:
>
> If key is nil and value is nil, returns an empty string.
>
> If key is nil and value is non-nil, returns value.
>
> **If key is not found and value is nil or an empty string, returns key.**
>
> If key is not found and value is non-nil and not empty, return value.

According to these rules, with the value set to `""` as it is in your function, if the key (`self`, in this case) isn't found, then the key (`self`) should be returned. I suspect `example_label` is coming from some default set somewhere in the rest of your code.

As a side note, I think this function would be nicer if written as a computed property.

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

Comment: "If key is not found and value is nil or an empty string, returns key." This is correct. I would like for it to search the English version of this key next instead of just returning the key itself.

Comment: @KotaBear233 Oh I figured your keys were the english strings. Okay, one sec

Comment: @KotaBear233 Where is this `example_label` coming from? `NSLocalizedString` tries every user language according to their priority, and falls back on english if none others are found.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I believe I found something to fix this for now.